# The request value is undefined

Tags: node.js, rest, express, body-parser

Please can someone help me ? i'm trying to write an api with node.js and express. When am doing a get request all is working fine but when i'm doing a POST it is also working but all the values are always undefined. I have included the middleware body-parser at te good postion but it doens't work anyway. Here is the code of my controller:

```
const DB_WRAPPER = require("../_helpers/dbHelper");
const db = new DB_WRAPPER();

module.exports = function(app) {
    app.get("/api/articles", async(req, res) => {
        const result = await db.getAll("SELECT * FROM articles");
        res.status(200).send(result);
    });
    
    app.get("/api/articles/:articleId", async(req, res) => {
        const id = req.params.articleId;
        const result = await db.getOne(`SELECT * FROM articles WHERE articleId = "${id}"`);
        res.status(200).send(result);
    });
    
    app.post("/api/articles", async(req, res) => {
        console.log(req)
        const body = req.body;
        console.log(req.body.titel)
        try {
            await db.cmd(`INSERT INTO articles 
            (titel, preis, beschreibung)
        VALUES ('${body.titel}','${body.preis}','${body.beschreibung}')`);
        } catch (e) {
            res.status(500).json({     
                error: e.toString()
            });
        }
        res.status(201).send({
            message: "article succesfully added"
        });
    });
    
    app.delete("/api/articles/:articleId", async(req, res) => {
        const id = req.params.articleId;
        try {
            await db.cmd(`DELETE FROM articles WHERE articleId = "${id}"`);
        } catch (error) {
            res.status(500).json({
                message: "Product doesnt exist"
            });
        }
        res.status(200).send({
            message: "Product Successfully deleted"
        });
    });

}
```

and the server.js file :

```
  const express = require("express");
    const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
    const cors = require('cors');
    
    const productController = require ('./controllers/productController');
    const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
    
    const app = express();


app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));


app.use(cors())

productController(app);


app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("The server started on: " + port);
});
```

Please can someone help me ? Thanks

Comment: Could it be that you have a typo? Look at this line: `console.log(req.body.titel)` - looks like it should be `console.log(req.body.title)`

Comment: No it is not, title = titel in german :) it is not the problem the req is undefined

Comment: Ah, thank you for the clarification

Comment: How do you make the request? Are you sending a JSON ? Have you check the request content-type ? The code looks all good to me, actually I tested it and it works just fine.

Comment: Yes I'm sending a JSON throught POSTMAN. I really don't know why it is not working. I also had build such a API in the past and it all worked fine. I really don't understand :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use routes to create different endpoints

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('<b>My</b> first express http server');
});

// 1) Add a route that answers to all request types
app.route('/article')
.get(function(req, res) {
    res.send('Get the article');
})
.post(function(req, res) {
    res.send('Add an article');
})
.put(function(req, res) {
    res.send('Update the article');
});

// 2) Use a wildcard for a route
// answers to : theANYman, thebatman, thesuperman
app.get('/the*man', function(req, res) {
    res.send('the*man');
});

// 3) Use regular expressions in routes
// responds to : batmobile, batwing, batcave, batarang
app.get(/bat/, function(req, res) {
    res.send('/bat/');
});

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.status(404).send("Sorry, that route doesn't exist. Have a nice day :)");
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000.');
});
```

Here you can find more examples [Express Samples](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/261/how-to-create-an-http-server-with-express-in-node-js)